# How to use ManagementEventWatcher in a windoes service?

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to use ManagementEventWatcher inside a C# .NET4 windows service application. At some point in the "OnStart" method I have these lines:

```
string scope = "\\root\\cimv2";
string query =
  "SELECT * FROM __InstanceCreationEvent " +
  "WITHIN 1 " +
  "WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_NTLogEvent' " +
  " AND ( " +
  "      targetInstance.EventCode = '4768' " + 
  "   OR targetInstance.EventCode = '4770' " + 
  "   OR targetInstance.EventCode = '672'" + 
  "   OR targetInstance.EventCode = '674'" + 
  " )";
eventListener = new ManagementEventWatcher(scope, query);
eventListener.EventArrived += new EventArrivedEventHandler(HandleEvent);


eventListener.Start();
```

The eventListener.Start(); line gives an exception with the message "Access Denied". I tried to set up my service as Administrator or LOCALSYSTEM but it does not help.

I also found this documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa392289(VS.85).aspx
But I can not figure out how to use it in C#.

The same code works as expected if put in a WindowsForms application.

Thanks.

Comment: How does it work if you configure the windows service to run impersonating your own windows account instead of Localsystem?

Comment: As I said in the question, I've put it to impersonate "Administrator", the only account on the system, and it still gets "Access Denied".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this is a problem with Windows XP. The code fails on it, but works on any newer Windows versions, starting with Windows 2003.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing inherent here that will prevent a service from providing this functionality.  I actually took your code and ran it fine on my machine as a service(famous developer last words) under the localsystem account.  If the account running lacks permissions to the event log, in your case, or anything else it needs it will bail.
A few general tips from my all-too-frequent experience with troubleshoooting similar problems:
1.  Remember that you can choose to "run as" for your windows form app to run under a different account than you happen to be logged in as.  I suspect running your windows form app with the Administrator account will fail exactly as your service did.
2. Selectively using security auditing can be very help in pinpointing access problems.
3. Using Sysinternals ProcMon can often pinpoint what exactly access is being denied to.
4. To make debugging as much of your service code as possible without it running as a service use the #DEBUG as suggested in this blog post (http://jclaes.blogspot.com/2010/03/cannot-start-service-from-command-line.html)

Comment: How to use ManagementEventWatcher in a windoes service?

Comment: Artur, you seem to spend a lot of time downvoting (16 downvotes) for a stack overflow reputation currently under 400.  I think my answer is on-point.

Comment: The service CAN write to logs, so there is no problem with logs access. Also if I run it in a windows forms application it works, even with administrator account without any problems. The problem is, that if I understood correctly from various google search results, a service can not simply access the windows WMI where the ManagementEventWatcher is, so your answer is not helping me. I also looked all over the logs and tried different tricks like using impersonation in the scope options, but that also didn't help.

Comment: Patkos, I tried out your scenario as best as I could.  I actually created and ran a service on my PC that successfully accessed WMI.  Accessing WMI via windows services is possible. This is why my answer focused on troubleshooting this as an access control issue.  Also, your link to the MSDN page for "Lowering the Security for a Sink in a Separate Process" is, I believe, irrelevant (unless your scenario has multiple processes involved).

Comment: Hmm, strange. What version of Windows do you have? Also, please try to put the `eventListener.Start();` into a `try { } catch { }` and tell me if it catches something. Thanks.

Comment: Patkos, I am running Windows 7.  Using your code the eventListener.Start doesn't throw an error on my PC.  I modified your query to observe all event log changes, and verified that the events were received.  I'd suggest either looking at my point 4 (I just added this) or looking at the results through ProcMon. Has ProcMon shown you anything interesting?

Comment: Thank you for your detailed suggestions. They did not solve my problem, but they deserve to be considered.